# Logback multiple loggers with different configuration

Tags: java, logging, logback

I want to use 2 different loggers in a class where one logger uses one logback configuration file and another uses another configuration file. eg:

```java
class Sample {
    // LOGGER 1 follows configuration from logback1.xml
    private static final LOGGER1 = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Sample.class);

    // LOGGER 2 follows configuration from logback2.xml
    private static final LOGGER2 = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Sample.class);

    public myFunc(){
        LOGGER1.info("In myFunc"); // writes to file as configured in logback1.xml
        LOGGER2.info("Entered myFunc"); // writes to graylog server as configured in logback2.xml
    }
}
```

The reason I want to do this is that I'm injecting a second logger into code at runtime, and I don't want the injected logger to collide with the logger used in the main project. How should I go about doing this?

I went through this post: [How to use multiple configurations with logback in a single project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6699537/how-to-use-multiple-configurations-with-logback-in-a-single-project) But it seems to address the problem of choosing one configuration file from many but not "being able to use 2 configuration files simultaneously as in the above example."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one way to get two loggers from different configs:

```
    LoggerContext c1 = new LoggerContext();
    LoggerContext c2 = new LoggerContext();
    new ContextInitializer(c1).configureByResource(new URL("file:logback1.xml"));
    new ContextInitializer(c2).configureByResource(new URL("file:logback2.xml"));
    Logger l1 = c1.getLogger("x");
    Logger l2 = c2.getLogger("x");
```