# Two logback configurations in a single app

Tags: java, logback

I'm working on a plugin to an existing app.

The existing app already uses logback.

I want to have my own logback configuration with my own loggers.

I have no access to the app logback.xml.

Is there a way to create a custom configuration for my plugin ? Because the goal is to have distinct logs for the plugin.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use multiple configurations with logback in a single project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6699537/how-to-use-multiple-configurations-with-logback-in-a-single-project)

Comment: Not sure. The jar we produce is included in a bigger app and we can't specify launch parameters with -D I will try to add a property. Thanks